# Como alinhar texto em um menu "mobile" usando a tag "select"

Tags: mobile, menu, css

Eu tenho um website (estruturaonline.com.br) *responsive* e quando acesso o menu em um PC simulando um dispositivo móvel o texto está alinhado ao [centro](http://www.estruturaonline.com.br/example/PC.gif) mas quando acesso usando um dispositivo móvel propriamente dito o texto fica alinhado à [esquerda](http://www.estruturaonline.com.br/example/MOBILE.png).

Tenho o seguinte código em meu site:

`index.html`:

```html
        <nav>
            <ul class="sf-menu">
                <li><a href="#lk1">A gente!</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Como foi?</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">O que falam?</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Dos projetos</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Da EstruturaOnline</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#lk2">WWW o qu&ecirc;?</a></li>
                <li><a href="#lk3">Voc&ecirc;s</a></li>
                <li><a href="#lk4">Fizemos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#lk5">Fazemos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#lk6">Fale</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

CSS:

```css
    .select-menu{
        background: #292929;
        background: url(../images/all/select_165x60.png) no-repeat scroll 100% center;
        background-position: 100% center;
        border: 0px !important;
        color: #EEEEEE;
        font: 900 13px "Architects Daughter";
        height: 60px;
        text-align: center !important;
        text-overflow: "";
        width: 100%;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
```

jQuery:

```js
(function(a){a.fn.mobileMenu=function(d){var c={defaultText:"Menu",className:"select-menu",subMenuClass:"sub-menu",subMenuDash:"&ndash;"},b=a.extend(c,d),e=a(this);this.each(function(){var g=a(this),f;g.find("ul").addClass(b.subMenuClass);var f=a("<select />",{"class":b.className+" "+e.get(0).className}).insertAfter(g);a("<option />",{value:"#",text:b.defaultText}).appendTo(f);g.find("a").each(function(){var h=a(this),j=" "+h.text(),l=h.parents("."+b.subMenuClass),i=l.length,k;if(h.parents("ul").hasClass(b.subMenuClass)){k=Array(i+1).join(b.subMenuDash);j=k+j}a("<option />",{value:this.href,html:j,selected:(this.href==window.location.href)}).appendTo(f)});f.change(function(){var h=a(this).val();if(h!=="#"){window.location.href=a(this).val()}});a(".select-menu").show()});return this}})(jQuery);$(document).ready(function(){$(".sf-menu").mobileMenu()});
```

Comment: Tens algum erro na consola? estás a carregar o jQuery mobile?

Comment: Está sim, perfeitamente, dá uma olhada através do celular e do PC. No PC redimensione a tela até ficar com uns 470px que verá como a tela de um celular! Depois olhe através de um celular. Não faço idéia do que pode ser...

Comment: PC: http://www.estruturaonline.com.br/example/PC.gif
MOBILE: http://www.estruturaonline.com.br/example/MOBILE.png

Comment: Qual o browser que estás a usar no Desktop e no device mobile?

Comment: Tentei em todos...

Comment: Pode ser uma questão de suporte! Talvez o navegador do seu celular ta "atrasado" e não aceita! Verifica a compatibilidade

Answer (score 1):

O alinhamento do texto dentro do menu suspenso gerado pelo seletor é definido pelo estilo padrão do navegador e pode variar de acordo com o dispositivo. Para alinhar o texto ao centro, você pode adicionar a seguinte propriedade de estilo:

```
text-align-last: center;
```

Para aplicar essa propriedade de estilo somente aos itens do menu suspenso gerado pelo seletor, você pode usar o seletor de classe ".select-menu option", que selecionará todos os elementos "option" dentro do seletor com a classe "select-menu". O código CSS atualizado seria assim:

Para mais informações de text-align:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/text-align

Answer (score 0):

quando vc alinha o sf-menu como center, este receberá por padraõ o center. para os sub-itens tente ser mais preciso como por exemplo para alinhar o texto dos itens li e ul tente usar:

```
.sf-menu  li, sf-menu li ul li{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Eu tentei, mas não funcionou, de qq forma obrigado, fiz de uma forma diferente...